# Jquery expanding the hover area

Tags: jquery, html

This is my my result html

[Output http://img2.pict.com/fc/c7/94/3241379/0/20100328195141.png](http://img2.pict.com/fc/c7/94/3241379/0/20100328195141.png)

And html of it is like this

```
<li id="33">
    <div class="todoRow">
        <span class="status_1">Test13</span>
        <img class="delete_todo" alt="Delete" src="trash.png">
    </div>
</li>
```

I am using `toggleClass` to change the class of span on hover. I want to make it hover-able till the width of delete icon so I can toggle the class

I dont want to use `div` to trigger the hover because in that case when trash icon is hovered it toggles class of span element too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the span doesn't actually go that far (because it's not a block element), you can see this by applying a border to it.  To fix this, give your span a CSS rule, something like:

```
.todoRow span { display: inline-block; width: 160px; }
```

Of course, adjust the width as needed.